# using scrapy scrape some information

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.baroul-bucuresti.ro/index.php?urlpag=tablou-definitivi&p=1']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        base_url='https://www.baroul-bucuresti.ro'
        soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        tra = soup.find_all('div',class_='panel-title')
        productlinks=[]
        for links in tra:
            for link in links.find_all('a',href=True)[1:]:
                comp=base_url+link['href']
                yield Request(comp, callback=self.parse_book)
     
    d1=''
    def parse_book(self, response):
        title=response.xpath("//h1//text()").get()
        detail=response.xpath("//div[@class='av_bot_left left']//p")
        for i in range(len(detail)):
           
            if 'Decizia de intrare:' in detail[i].get():
                d1=response.xpath("//em[@class='ral_i']//text()").get()
                print(d1)
```

They will provide me these output:

```
Decizia de intrare:
```

But the actual output that I want is these as you  seen below the page of the website https://www.baroul-bucuresti.ro/avocat/15655/aanegroae-ana-maria :

```
Decizia de intrare: 2469/1-06.12.16
```

Comment: `d1= ' '.join(txt.strip() for txt in detail[i].xpath(".//text()").extract() if txt.strip())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

Instead of taking the xpath of the root node in your if statement I take the xpath of the node you have already identified as having the text you desire.  Then I just do some string formatting.

```
   def parse_book(self, response):
        title=response.xpath("//h1//text()").get()
        detail=response.xpath("//div[@class='av_bot_left left']//p")
        for i in range(len(detail)):
           
            if 'Decizia de intrare:' in detail[i].get():
                d1=detail[i].xpath('.//text()').getall()  
                d1 = " ".join([i.strip() for i in d1 if i.strip()])
                print(d1)
```

Comment: if I want to get only these  `2469/1-06.12.16` in my output what I will do it

Comment: like these =`" ".join(d[-1])`

Comment: like this `d1 = [i.strip() for i in d1 if i.strip()][-1]`